# Python: Run WSGI server from inetd?

Tags: python, wsgi, inetd

As the title suggests, is it possible to run a WSGI server from (x)inetd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](http://gist.github.com/83986), but don't do it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks (and, yes, I know that `inetd` is on par with `cgi`… But, well, sometimes it's the simplest thing that'll work)